# Solving a first order ordinary differential equation with no initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following differential equation. $$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{3y - 3x}{2x+3y} $$

---

Answer:

Let $y = xv$. Then we have:

\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= x \dfrac{dv}{dx} + v \\
v &= \dfrac{ y}{x} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &=
 \dfrac{ 3\left( \dfrac{y}{x} \right)  - 3} {2+3\left( \dfrac{y}{x}\right) } \\ 
x \dfrac{dv}{dx} + v &= \dfrac{3v-3}{2+3v} \\
x \dfrac{dv}{dx}  &= \dfrac{3v-3 - v(2+3v)}{2+3v} \\
x \dfrac{dv}{dx}  &= \dfrac{3v-3 -2v - 3v^2}{2+3v} \\
x \dfrac{dv}{dx}  &= \dfrac{-3v^2+v-3}{3v+2} \\
\dfrac{dx}{x} &= \dfrac{ 3v + 2}{-3v^2 + v -3 } \,\,\, dv
\end{align*}
Using  an  online integral calculator, I find:
$$ \int \dfrac{ 3x+2 }{ -3x^2 + x - 3} \,\, dv =
 -\dfrac{ \ln( 3x^2 - x + 3 ) }{2} +
 \dfrac{4 \arctan\left( \dfrac{ 6x - 1 }{ \sqrt{35} } \right)  } { \sqrt{35} }.
  + C$$
Now we have:
\begin{align*} 
\ln{x} &=
 -\dfrac{ \ln( 3v^2 - v + 3 ) }{2} +
 \dfrac{4 \arctan\left( \dfrac{ 6v - 1 }{ \sqrt{35} } \right)  } { \sqrt{35} }.
 + C
\end{align*}
According to ChatGPT, the correct solution is:
$$ y = (2x+3y)(x+C) $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: First you cant have $v$ in your final answer. Only $y$ and $x$.

Comment: Checking with a CAS, it looks like the arctangents should have $5$ in the numerator not $4$. But it otherwise it seems correct. On the other side, you can solve ChatGPT's proposed solution for $y$ as a function of $x$ and thus check by hand whether it actually satisfies the ODE. (As far as I can tell, it doesn't...)

Comment: @Semiclassical You are right, the 4 should be a 5. It was a typo. I also tried to verify ChatGPT's solution. I could not.

Comment: ChatGPT interpolates text fragments found on the net to produce something that looks correct on first reading, however it is no CAS like WolframAlpha. Answers to higher mathematical questions will be almost always fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Are the coefficients on the right correct? The equation would be in a class with more structure if the nominator were $2y-3x$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I made up the problem. The coefficients are correct. No typo there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that
$$y=(2x+3y)(x+c)\iff y=\frac{2x(x+c)}{-3(x+c)+1},$$when $(x+c)\not=\frac{1}{3}$. Setting $c=0$ and find $dy/dx$ we have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2(2-3x)x}{(3x-1)^2}\not=\frac{3(\frac{2x^2}{1-3x})-3x}{2x+3(\frac{2x^2}{1-3x})}.$$
So your function $y$ is not solution of the ode.

Instead, your first way is correct. Setting the substitution $y/x:=v$ we need to solve the ode
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}+v=\frac{3(v-1)}{3v+2}$$
Thus, we get by variable separation
$$-\sqrt{\frac{5}{7}}\arctan(\frac{6v-1}{\sqrt{35}})-\frac{1}{2}\ln|3v^2-v+3|=\ln|x|+c,$$with $c$ be an arbitrary constant, then substitution back give the implicit solution.